# Ubuntu 16.04 Systemd not possible to use systemctl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, systemctl

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server, since the last restart, 
systemctl doesn't work anymore.

For example if I want to start the nginx, I get the following error:

```
root@SERVER:/# systemctl start nginx
Failed to start nginx.service: Unknown unit: nginx.service
```

The same result for every other service.
Just systemctl gives the following result:

```
root@SERVER:/# systemctl
Failed to list units: No such method 'ListUnitsFiltered'
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's specifically changed in your distro, but do you have a reason for not calling it with `service nginx start` or via `/system.d`?

Comment: Or has the nginx.service been moved, renamed, or unlinked?

Comment: No the nginx.Service still exists and I got the Same result for any other Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something is seriously messed up with your OS.  Perhaps you accidentally moved or deleted files or something.

Simply invoking systemctl on its own should produce output like:

```
UNIT                                                                     LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount                                        loaded active running   Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:07.1-ata2-host1-target1:0:0-1:0:0:0-block-sr0.device loaded active plugged   VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive
```

It seems like something is broken and suspect it will affect more than systemctl.  Could you start services using service or init.d style startup?

If you can't then I imagine your unfortunately better off with a fresh re-install.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues after upgrading my 14.04 Ubuntu to 16.04. Somehow, the `systemd` packages did not install properly and I had the same problems as described in this question. The solution was to reinstall the relevant packages:

```
apt-get install --reinstall systemd-sysv ubuntu-standard
```

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers for more info.

Comment: Fixed it, had to restart as well.
Problem was that I installed upstart